# wpf how to translate itemssource

Tags: wpf, itemssource

I'm new to wpf and i have a question as follow.
I have a class Node whose defination is

```
class Node{
    public int id{get; set;}
    public List<int> son_ids{get;set;}
}
```

I want to use treeview to show a hirerachical structure, so I write a HierarchicalDataTemplate like this

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding son_ids}" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I want to show the tree recursively, but as i know, the itemssource is a list that represents the data sets in the next hirerarchy, so the type of son_ids should be list of Nodes instead of list of ints. The reason i use list of ints is that i want to retrieve each Node object in a hashtable like hash[node_id]. How can i apply to each element(ele) on son_ids to get hash[ele] as the item in the next hirerarchy? Or is there any other approach? Thanks

Comment: There are two ways to do this. You can use a `IValueConverter` to convert the `int` to `node`, but you would need to inject the context into the `IValueConverter` which would be hard. The other way, which I would recommend, is to wrap each node in a `ViewModel` and have that do the conversion. I would recommend a library like `ReactiveUI` for the mappings.

Comment: thanks, I finally decided to change the list to list of nodes